# Return both OUT parameters and a rowset

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I would like to return both output parametrs and a rowset.

In DB2, I can accomplish this with the following, and opening a cursor before the stored procedure ended:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE rqstprtl.getInfo (
    IN  id  BIGINT,
    OUT var1    CHAR(6),
    OUT var2    BIGINT
)
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
```

I'm unsure how to accomplish the same thing with PostgreSQL functions. My understanding is that functions have a return type of `record` (or no return type) for functions that have output parameters, but I would also need a return type of `setof record` to return the rowset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a refcursor instead, so one OUT parameter should be a refcursor type.

Pavel